Can I be a robotics software engineer, and how?
I am a Web Application software engineer, I use web technologies(MySQL, PHP, JavaScript, etc.) to build websites daily. I have a computer science degree.
I'd like to be a robotics software engineer, since I sense that robotics is the future. I see many real world applications: Robot arms in the factory; Autonomous mobile robot that can pick up, transport, and drop off containers in Amazon fulfillment facilities; Etc...
My questions are

Is there such profession as robotics software engineer? Meaning, if I learned enough staff can I find a job in robotics industry as a software engineer? I don't know much about hardware, I only understand software.
If there is such profession as robotics software engineer, what do I need to learn to find a position? And what do I need to learn to be an expert?
Any other advice or comment on my plan is welcomed


yes, you can ...

Welcome to Robotics shintaroid but I'm afraid that Life Questions are off-topic. Choosing how to spend your time (books to read, classes to take, projects to construct, career to pursue etc.) may be difficult, but it's specific to you, so unlikely to help future visitors. Questions like this are welcome in [chat] when you have the privilege. We prefer practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face, see [ask] & [about].

What exactly prevents you from studying path planning on the top of ROS, using, say, Python (or you can also try Rust or C++ for more ambitions)?

You can be Robotics Software Engineer with following tutorials. You should start learning ROS, Python and C++. Additional, you can follow Control Theory lessons online from universities. If you have budget, you can learn these lessons from The Construct (https://www.theconstruct.ai/). Robotics Field is fun and promising field.
Edit:
@Christian Fritz I don't agree with you. Yes, he can be developer but if he doesn't learn mathematic and control theory, he can't design a robot which has required move from A to B autonomously. Assuming that you want to design a differential drive robot. You should know kinematics or dynamics of differential drive vehicle. After that, you need to communicate with MCU (Motor Controller Unit) and you need to use C++ or Python and ROS. In conclusion, what I said at the beginning will be valid. Please do not mislead people who want to try a new field.
You are talking about development with libraries like roslib, rosnodejs, etc., which can communicate with ROS. However, we need to understand that using these and developing backend-frontend systems does not necessarily fall under the scope of robotics software engineering. Everyone starts a business from the beginning. What matters is the path to be taken.
As I said, I have started with ROS, C++, Python, JavaScript and Control & Calculus (as beginner).
For ROS: Hello Ros World - EDX
C++: Deitel C++
Python: Python3 for Robotics
Control Theory: Control Theory (Standford University) You can follow online lessons for Control and Calculus

My advise to you is very different from @furkansariyildiz's. I recently added this perspective to one of those collaborative articles on LinkedIn:

Many roboticists overlook the need for JavaScript in their skill set and tech stack. This is because of the evolution of robotics projects and companies: first you build a prototype and only then do you deploy and scale your fleet. The first part is hard and doesn't require any JS. But the second part is even harder and requires a ton of JS, because without web-tooling you won't be able to operate efficiently. This offers a great opportunity for roboticists to distinguish themselves from others be mastering JS for both the backend (rosnodejs, rclnodejs) and the front-end (React, Transitive). This sets you apart from both "regular" roboticists and from "pure" web developers.

So rather than trying to "exchange" your web skills for low-level robotics software skills, I would advise you to learn enough about ROS so that you can use the above mentioned technologies, including the open-source framework I'm developing (Transitive) for enabling web development for robots. People with that combination of skills are in demand.

It is very uncommon to drive robots using JavaScript. Python is used for prototyping, C++ or Rust for production versions. Many robots also have vendor-specific languages.

I never suggested to "drive robots" using JS. But if you've ever worked with more than a handful of robots, you'll know that to scale your fleet you'll need web-tooling, and for that you'll need to know JS.
